# Doctrine query builder как указать поля связи в выборке

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2, querybuilder

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой, как указать при выборке поля в query builder, которые являются связующими (в моём случае много ко многим)?

Сущность User

```
 ...
     /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
         *
         */
        protected $roles;
```

Сущность Role

```
...
     /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
         */
        private $users;
```

Запрос строю в репозитории сущности User так:

```
public function loadListOfUsers($fields = array('u')){

    $query = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select($fields);

    $users = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $users;
}
```

В контроллере:

```
 public function getAction()
{
    $fields = array(
        'u.id',
        'u.username',
        'u.email',
        'u.avatar',
        'u.isActive',
        'u.roles',
    );

    $restresult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppUserBundle:User')->loadListOfUsers($fields);

    if ($restresult === null) {
        return new View("there are no users exist", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return $restresult;
}
```

Если убрать u.roles, всё ок. Но нужно получать и роли, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: не понятно а что в базе есть такое поле вообще? и что за ошибка (Exception) у вас?

Comment: Имеется 3 таблицы, users roles и users_roles которые связанны как u.id = u_r.user_id и u_r.role_id = r.id. Т.е. связь много ко многим через промежуточную таблицу users_roles. Поле roles в таблице нет, это доктриновская связь, которая содержит массив ролей которые принадлежат юзеру. Вопрос в том как построить запрос что бы получить эти роли и указать только нужные поля, если спросить всё, то приходит и пароль и ещё много чего, что не нужно. Фильтровать на стороне сервера как то не кашерно ИМХО.